Can I ask Allah to punish me for cheating on my partner?
I confessed to my partner about cheating on her multiple times. She is now depressed and says she may never recover or trust anyone again.
I've been praying 2 Nafals with each prayer, asking Allah to ease her pain. However, I feel like I need to suffer more to make up for what I did to her.
Is it wrong to ask Allah to punish me for my actions so I get what I deserve? I don't feel worthy of His forgiveness as I haven't been a good Muslim until after the breakup.
Thank you for your answers.
